# bring maven profiles information on jsp

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, maven-profiles

I have maven properties on pom.xml as follow

pom.xml

```
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <env>local</env>

        </properties>

    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>prod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

if I want what env value from jsp
what should I do? 
I want to use this value like

```
<c:when test=env=='local'>
</c:when>
<c:when test=env=='dev'>
</c:when>
<c:when test=env=='env'>
</c:when>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing Maven profiles (a build time construct) with Spring profiles (runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [maven resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) which works like this:

Create a build.properties in src/main/resources like:

```
env=${env}
```

Then add the resource filter to your pom

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <env>prod</env>
</properties>

<build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

</build>
```

After a build your build,properties will look like :

```
greg@greg-XPS-13-9360:~/work/jsp-example$ cat target/classes/build.properties 
env=prod
```

You can inject them into the JSP in the normal way, for my [example](https://github.com/gregclinker/jsp-example) I used Spring boot.

Note if you use Spring Boot the build.properties should be of the format

```
greg@greg-XPS-13-9360:~/work/jsp-example$ cat src/main/resources/build.properties 
env=@env@
```

Comment: I tried  @Value("${env}")
 private String env;   but nothing show up

Comment: @minakim look at the working example, I've tested it works fine :)

Comment: can you show me the example with my pom.xml's profiles setting

Comment: not using spring boot . LOGGER.info("envvv->{}", this.env); will show  envvv->${env}